Get rid of big icon item in Messages app’s list of conversations
Apple’s Messages app displays a list of conversation threads on the left side.
In the current version of iOS and iPadOS, the first items are displayed as a large icon, unlike all the items below that. This is confusing, and leads me to sending messages on the wrong thread.
Here is a screenshot from Apple.com web site, showing six of these large icons.

Is there some way to revert to the old behavior, a simple list of threads, all displayed in the same manner?

I see six large icons. Are these the conversations which you want to remove?

@nohillside Yes. Screenshot from Apple.com web site.

“Pinned” conversation
You have inadvertently “pinned” a conversation, a way to keep handy a particular conversation thread.
You can remove the pinning.

In the Messages app, tap the Edit link found in the corner of screen.
Tap the Edit pins link.
On the icon that annoys you, tap the grey circle with Minus Sign icon.
Tap Done.

Tapping the Minus Sign icon does not delete to the conversation thread, it merely clears your previous inadvertent pinning.
